# Steam wont launch ubuntu 18.04

Tags: steam

Downloaded and installed the deb from the steam site and clicking the launcher just does nothing, however there is a steam instance running in the system monitor. Trying to launch through the terminal gives me this text

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I have no idea what to do right now, any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Update: ran these 2 commands

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

and now when running steam in the terminal i get this

```
Repairing installation, linking /home/alex/.steam/steam to /home/alex/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
/home/alex/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_send_request_with_fds
/home/alex/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 444: no match: ssfn*
```

Comment: What video card and driver are you using?
`for s in $(lspci | grep VGA | awk '{print $1}'); do lspci -v -s $s; done`

Answer (score 0):

Well randomly deleting things doesn't usually make your life much easier... First thing always to try is have you re-installed it? Like fully:

```
sudo apt purge steam
```

then re-installing?

I had install problems on 18.04 and they were fixed by just re-installing.

Also might just be me but you'll probably find a better version for 18.04 through either the Ubuntu Software Center or by installing it through aptitude as shown below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update && sudo apt install steam
```

oh also make sure you're running the right graphics drivers steam can get fussy. You should be able to find them through Software & Updates>Additional Drivers>Nvidea-Radeon(not the normally selected open source one)

Goodluck bud, I'm rootin for ya

Comment: I figured it out, apparently i had 2 versions installed (?) and simply uninstalling through the software center worked